# Go DynamoDB Query returns no item with Filter and Limit=1

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I've following dynamoDB table

| user_id | date | game |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2021-12-06 14:36:46 | game1 |
| user1 | 2021-12-06 15:36:46 | game1 |
| user1 | 2021-12-07 11:36:46 | game2 |
| user1 | 2021-12-07 12:36:46 | game2 |

**partition key**: user_id

**sort key**: date

I want to Query the latest entry of user for game `game1`
(Which is the second item from table with date `2021-12-06 15:36:46`). I can achieve this from code as follows;

```
expr, _ := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithKeyCondition(expression.Key("user_id").Equal(expression.Value("user1"))).
    WithFilter(expression.Name("game").Equal(expression.Value("game1"))).
    Build()
var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    KeyConditionExpression:    expr.KeyCondition(),
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
    FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
    ScanIndexForward:          aws.Bool(false),
    TableName:                 aws.String(table),
}
```

This returns me all items of user `user1` for game `game1`. Problem occurs when I apply limit=1 `Limit: aws.Int64(1)` in QueryInput, it returns nothing. Could someone explain why is that so ?

When I change `Limit: aws.Int64(4)` (total number of items in table), only then the query returns single expected item. How is this limit working ?

Do I need to use `game` as GSI ?

Answer (score 4):

The limit on a DDB parameter is applied before your filter expressions.

Essentially with a limit of 1, it retrieves 1 record, then applies the filters and returns you the items that match (0).

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Limit for more details, copied in case link breaks

> Limiting the Number of Items in the Result Set

> The Query operation allows you to limit the number of items that it reads. To do this, set the Limit parameter to the maximum number of items that you want.

> For example, suppose that you Query a table, with a Limit value of 6, and without a filter expression. The Query result contains the first six items from the table that match the key condition expression from the request.

> Now suppose that you add a filter expression to the Query. In this case, DynamoDB reads up to six items, and then returns only those that match the filter expression. The final Query result contains six items or fewer, even if more items would have matched the filter expression if DynamoDB had kept reading more items.

Comment: I see. So filter is applied on client side, after the (limited) data is fetched from db. Then any suggestions on how to achieve latest item of user for given game?

Comment: I would let DDB return you everything it can (up to its max of 1MB of data). Then apply your filters. If you do not find a match and there is a page Token, then re-query DDB for the next 1MB of data.

Comment: @AnumSheraz - to get user high score by game, add a compound sort key (in the table or a new index) like `game1#2021-12-06 15:36:46`.  Query with `PK="user1" AND begins_with(SK, "game1")`, setting `ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false)` for descending order.  You are not filtering, so `Limit: aws.Int32(1)` will get you the most recent game1 record for user1.